# Stay on page after submitting form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, form-submit

I'm trying to stay on the current page from where a form gets submitted. But somehow it's not working. I found some peaces of code on the internet and put it together.

This is the process.php file:

```
<?php
// Get Data    
$name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$phone = strip_tags($_POST['phone']);
$subject = strip_tags($_POST['subject']);
$message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);

// Send Message
mail( "email@domain.com", "Contact Form testttt",
"Name: $name\nEmail: $email\nPhone: $phone\nWebsite: $url\nMessage: $message\n",
"From: Forms testtttttttt" );
?>
```

And the rest of the code, the html and javascripts can be found on jsfiddle:
[jsfiddled code](http://jsfiddle.net/4zYTD/1/)

```
    $(function(){
        $('#contact').validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
                $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                url: 'process.php',
                success: function() {
                    $('#contact').hide();
                    $('#contact-form').append("<p class='thanks'>thanks test.</p>")
                    }
                });
            }
        });         
    });
```

Forgot to mention what happens now. I get redirected to process.php page.

Comment: what happens when you sumit your form ?

Comment: Why do you use `strip_tags`? The data is not used in a HTML context so tags are not a problem at all.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, i just copied the source codes from different pages. I don't even know what that does.

Comment: You should not do this. Better learn how to do things on your own instead of just doing copy&paste.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, im learning things this way. But thanks for your advice.

Comment: This way of "learning" will turn you into a bad programmer. Especially for PHP there is *much* very bad code out there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function to submit a form without refreshing a page. You need to do something like this:

**test.php:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-version.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajaxform.js"></script>

<form action='process.php' method='post' class='ajaxform'>
 <input type='text' name='txt' value='Test Text'>
 <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

**process.php:**

```
<?php
      // Get your form data here in $_POST
?>
```

**ajaxform.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('.ajaxform').submit( function() {

        $.ajax({
            url     : $(this).attr('action'),
            type    : $(this).attr('method'),
            data    : $(this).serialize(),
            success : function( data ) {
                         alert('Form is successfully submitted');       
                      },
            error   : function(){
                         alert('Something wrong');
                      }
        });

        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: you're test.php, everything inside forms is with single quotes, why? Can i also use double quotes?

Comment: thanks, your code did the trick! I do have one small question though. How do i clear all the fields again when the form successfully got processed?

Comment: @Yustme: You can clear fields in success method of ajax function something like this `$('.ajaxform')[0].reset();`

Answer (score 6):

You need to either return [a 204 HTTP status](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.5) or make the request using JavaScript instead of by submitting the form (this is known as Ajax and there are numerous tutorials on the subject linked from the [jQuery tutorials page](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials)).

Answer (score -1):

This is a link to get you started :

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

Comment: How does he actually send the email? Don't you have to use php for that?