# Stay on page while downloading XML

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to submit an URL which creates an XML file while I stay on the same page. During my research, I found this [Stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570825/stay-on-page-after-submitting-form)

which gives me a good idea how my problem could be solved. Using PHP and Ajax should do the trick. I am able to submit a form and post process the values while staying on the same page. But how can I call a URL to download an XML file while staying on the same page ?

Do you have any hint for me ?

Comment: just like href ? or anchor tag works ?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specifics of your problem, you could open a new tab (or window) with javascript:

`window.open(url, '_blank');`

You could point the url to a php page and use the following code to download the file:

```php
$url = 'some/url/to/xml/file.xml

header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($url) . "\"");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($url));
```

You could then simply close the tab with javascript again:

`window.close();`